# Perl Test::More of verbose processes

Tags: perl

I'm writing a Perl test script with `Test::More` for a process that is very verbose. I'm trying to figure out a good practice for highlighting the **test results** out of the verbose process I'm testing.

```
use Test::More;

ok( verbose_process(), 'Test A of a verbose process' );
ok( verbose_process(), 'Test B of a verbose process' );
ok( verbose_process(), 'Test C of a verbose process' );

sub verbose_process{
   print "$_\n" for (0..100);
   return 1;
}
```

I'm imagining a way of asking `Test::More` for a test summary at the bottom of my script. Is such a thing possible? Or should I be suppressing the output of my verbose_pocess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture%3a%3aTiny) to capture STDOUT and STDERR from the process. You can then either test STDOUT/STDERR to make sure they contain expected data, or discard them if you consider that output to be unimportant.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;
use Capture::Tiny qw(capture);

my (undef, undef, $result_a) = capture { scalar verbose_process() };
ok($result_a, 'Test A of a verbose process');

my (undef, undef, $result_b) = capture { scalar verbose_process() };
ok($result_b, 'Test B of a verbose process');

my ($stdout_c, undef, $result_c) = capture { scalar verbose_process() };
ok($result_c, 'Test C of a verbose process');
like($stdout_c, qr/100\n\z/, '... and count to STDOUT ended correctly');

sub verbose_process {
   print "$_\n" for (0..100);
   return 1;
}

done_testing;
```

Comment: I'd like to keep all of the verbosity. The issue I'm having is that the test results are sparsely distributed throughout the process output.

Comment: Run the test script via `prove` which always prints a summary at the end?

Comment: Though personally I think when you run a test script it should only output the test results in TAP format and nothing else. TAP format does allow for diagnostic comments. Test::More provides `diag` and `note` functions for outputting diagnostics.

Comment: Cool, I was kind of wondering whether any verbosity was too much verbosity.